# Trigger minusing from one table to another table MYSQL

Tags: mysql

So, i have two table at the minute...

Freezing - (id, et1, straw, eps) &
Inventory - (id, et1, owner, total)

I need it so that when someone enters something into Freezing, and whatever is entered into 'EPS' in freezing will take off 'total' in Inventory. The common column between these 2 tables is the et1 number. Currently the statement I'm using below enters, however it does not affect the total in Inventory. If someone could help me see where i'm going wrong that would be brilliant.

```
UPDATE et1209_inventory 
SET total = total - "et1202_freezing.EPS"
WHERE "et1202_freezing.EPS" = total
```

Comment: Is there a question?

Comment: @P.Salmon, my mistake, in a rush and wrote this in a hurry. Have amended :)

Comment: I doubt this is ever the case WHERE "et1202_freezing.EPS" = total

Comment: Hmmm okay, what am i best changing this to? I've tried a couple different things and cannot get it to work the way i need

Comment: Is there any difference between the last question you asked and what was wrong with the answer I gave?

Comment: I appreciate the answer on this question and the previous question- however these are different tables, and using the advice you gave, i unfortunately cannot get it working between these two tables.

Comment: You could improve this question by providing , sample data, the process involved (update,insert) end expected outcome as text.

Comment: `"et1202_freezing.EPS"` is a string

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly it would probably be the easiest to just create a third table that joins Freezing and Inventory:

```
create table if not exists Output_table as
select i.id, i.et1, i.owner, f.eps - i.total
from Freezing f
join Inventory i on f.id = i.id;
```